# Membership.ValidateUser works for IE10 but not Firefox

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication

Earlier today I had no problem, but this afternoon something (and I've no clue what) changed in my Forms Based Authentication setup in SharePoint 2013, so that while I can login to my site using IE10, I can no longer do so with Firefox or Chrome.

Essentially I found, while debugging my custom login script in Visual Studio, that the following line of code returns `true` when using IE10 (both locally on the server and remotely from my desktop), but when I use other browsers the line returns `false`. I can't explain why

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(formUserName, formPassword))
```

I've checked the values of `formUserName` and `formPassword` and they match between using IE and FF, which makes this even more bizzare. I've also cleared everything from within FF (cookies, cache, etc.) and still no joy.

Comment: Have you validated that the same information is being passed in for the formUserName and formPassword values between browsers? Maybe add a breakpoint and debug to see what the values are with the different browsers.

Comment: Did u changed anything in your web.config file ?

Comment: @JohnChapman I did validate that (see last sentence of my question). Because those values are the same, it makes this that much more strange and difficult to resolve.

Comment: @Pushpendra _I_ didn't change anything, but I suppose I should check incase something was changed without my knowledge. I'll get back to you

Comment: @Pushpendra nope, nothing hsa changed in the web.config. Any other ideas?

Comment: hey..pls have a look at this and also could u share ur config file.

Comment: I found the answer, but what is 'this' in your last msg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find the answer - SharePoint 2013 has two 'hives', 14 & 15. I'm not sure how, but my login.aspx file in the /14/LAYOUTS folder was not the same as the (correct) /15/LAYOUTS/login.aspx, and this caused the issues. Once both files were teh same, the browser type didn't matter, and I can login.